# having problems with authentication if i use if statement

Tags: c++, text-files, c-strings

There is an error when i try to compile and im not sure whats wrong with it.
This is a program which authencate username and password with textfile, seperated with ";" delimeter in a single textfile.
The error is quite long.

```
/tmp/ccgs7RYV.o: In function 'Employee::Employee()':
main2.cpp:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to 'Employee::authenticate(std::basic_string, std::allocator>, std::basic_string, std::allocator>)'
/tmp/ccgs7RYV.o: In function `Employee::Employee()':
main2.cpp:(.text+0x231): undefined reference to 'Employee::authenticate(std::basic_string, std::allocator>, std::basic_string, std::allocator>)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Employee
{
public:
Employee();
bool authenticate(string, string);
};

Employee::Employee()
{
    string username, password;
    cout << "Username: ";
    cin >> username;

    cout << "Password: ";
    cin >> password;

    if (authenticate(username, password) == true)
        cout << "Sucess" << endl;
    else
        cout << "fail" << endl; 
}

bool authenticate(string username, string password) 
{
    std::ifstream file("login.txt");
    std::string fusername, fpassword;

    while (!file.fail()) 
    {
        std::getline(file, fusername, ';'); // use ; as delimiter
        std::getline(file, fpassword); // use line end as delimiter
        // remember - delimiter readed from input but not added to output

        if (fusername == username && fpassword == password)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}


int main()
{
    Employee();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please 1) stop using the [homework] tag, it says in the description to stop using it 2) start tagging your questions with the programming language you're writing in.

Comment: Your while loops is essentially broken. You don't need the `fail()`, but you *must* check the return value of `getline`.

Comment: classes were not really designed to be invoked as temporaries like that with all logic in the constructor.

Why not have Employee as an object then give it a method authenticate that takes the input file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bool Employee::authenticate(string username, string password) {
std::ifstream file("login.txt");
std::string fusername, fpassword;

while (!file.fail()) {
    std::getline(file, fusername, ';'); // use ; as delimiter
    std::getline(file, fpassword); // use line end as delimiter
    // remember - delimiter readed from input but not added to output
    if (fusername == username && fpassword == password)
        return true;
}
```

You need to use the scope resolution operator. You were just missing that.

Comment: omg cant imagine its a silly error :(, thank for pointing it out !!

Comment: It happens to the best of us. Remember to accept :P (as well as your other questions).

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'm going to try to sort out class design a bit.

```
class Employee
{
public:
      Employee( std::string name, std::string password ) :
          m_name( name ), m_password( password )
      {
      }

      bool authenticate( const char * filename ) const;

private:
      std::string m_name;
      std::string m_password;
};

Employee readEmployeeFromConsole()  
{
      std::string name, password;
     std::cout << "Name: ";
     std::cin >> name;
     std::cout << "Password: "
     std::cin >> password;
     return Employee( name, password );
}

bool Employee::authenticate( const char * filename ) const
{
      // your implementation
}

int main()
{
    Employee emp = readEmployeeFromConsole();
    if( emp.authenticate( "input.txt" ) )
    {
         std::cout << "You're in!\n";
    }
    else
    {
         std::cout << "Get out!\n";
    }
}
```